# Login from one Drupal instance on another Drupal instance

Tags: 6, users, authentication-authorization

I'm working on a project that has some unconventional requirements.

Basically, I have two sites, each one with an individual Drupal installation and instance. The main site (I'll call it "master") has a lot of registered users, and the other one does not (I'll call it "slave").

I need the possibility of logging into the "master" site through the "slave" one. Like, the "slave" site would have a login form, that would connect to the "master" site and authenticate the user.

I've thought of using APIs like OAuth for this, but I didn't find any solid documentation or tutorial of how to do this with Drupal.

*Observations: I can't make them multisites, they are two isolated Drupal instances. And it must work for Drupal 6.*

Can anyone give me some directions?

Comment: Are you referring to subdomains of the same domain, such as localize.drupal.org and groups.drupal.org?

Comment: Actually not, both sites are completely individual Drupal instances, running in different vhosts and domains.

Comment: I have just another question. Do you also want that a user who is already logged-in the slave site appears as logged-in in the master site, independently from a session being open for that user in the master site? In one case, the user who logs in on the slave site would not need to log in on the master site too; in the other case, the slave site would not require the user to create an account, if the user has already an account on the master site. To make an example, when you log in on drupal.org, you are also logged-in on groups.drupal.org, and vice versa.

Comment: Single Sign On would be an extra, but I'm not considering it at this point. I just want the slave site to use the users from the master one. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [Single Sign On](http://drupal.org/project/sso) module. It's only for Drupal 6, which is what you need, but it's not actively maintained. If it works as advertised, I think you are good to go.

There is also the [Bakery Single Sign-On System](http://drupal.org/project/bakery), but I don't think it fits your specs and requirements.

Comment: Bakery works for subdomains, such as localize.drupal.org and groups.drupal.org, as it uses cookies for working.

Comment: hmm, I'll take a look at the SSO module... thanks!